# Leaf at same level in binary tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

Given a Binary Tree, check if all leaves are at same level or not.

Input:

```
        10
      /    \
    20      30
   /  \        
 10    15
```

Output: 0

Explanation:
Leaves 10, 15 and 30 are not at same level.
**Approach:** The height of left subtree and right subtree should be same for each node. 

**My Code:**

```
int height(Node* root){
    if(root == NULL) return 0;
    return 1 + max(height(root->left), height(root->right));
}
bool check(Node *root)
{
    if(root == NULL) return true;
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) return true;
    if(root->left == NULL || root->right == NULL) return false;
    int l = height(root->left);
    int r = height(root->right);
    if(l == r) return true;
    return false;
    
}
```

**ISSUE:** This code doesn't work for multiple test cases though. Can someone help me figure out why?
**Testcase failed:** 
2910 7670 N 712 4700 N 8459 2271 N 332 8570 N 7403 8390 N 9496 8400 N 8771 6683 N 1647 440 N 1979 1254

Its Correct output is:
1

And my Code's output is:
0

**String Representation:**
[image]

Comment: what test cases fail? Please include a [mcve], input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: So in your failing example, what are the values of `height(root->left)` and `height(root->right)`? And what _should_ they be?

Comment: so far, question improved a lot, [mcve] is still missing though

Comment: In your testcase root->right height 0. Correct ?

Comment: Please explain your test case

Comment: According to testcase and string representation it should be 0.

Comment: You don't state, which version of the c++ std this example should adhere to.
Generally, AFAIK, it is discouraged to compare a pointer to anything other than `nullptr` . So your `== NULL` should rather be `== nullptr` (which, in turn, might be omitted, because testing a pointer automatically evaluates if it is `!=nullptr` -> true, oder `==nullptr` .> false).

Comment: I found this question on geeksforgeeks and it failed for the above testcase. @molbdnilo

Comment: @kaba `NULL` is a null pointer constant. The problem with it is that it's implementation-defined whether it is convertible to `int`

Comment: @kaba maybe its a matter of wording, but "Generally, AFAIK, it is discouraged to compare a pointer to anything other than nullptr" is not right. Eg there is absolutely no problem to have two pointers and compare them via `a == b` (even if none of them is a `nullptr`)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818  Agreed. Thanks for the clarification. (Had a faint notion that my sentence might not be well phrased, but didn't want to make it overly complicated to read. This way it came out wrong...)

Comment: Apparently, usage of BFS would be natural here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only checking that the deepest leaf to the left of root is at the same height as the deepest leaf to the right of root. You need to check the minimum height against the maximum height.

```
std::pair<int, int> heights(Node * node) {
    if (node->left && node->right) {
        auto [lmin, lmax] = heights(node->left);
        auto [rmin, rmax] = heights(node->right);
        return { 1 + std::min(lmin, rmin), 1 + std::max(rmax, lmax) };
    } else if (node->left) {
        auto [min, max] = heights(node->left);
        return { 1 + min, 1 + max };
    } else if (node->right) {
        auto [min, max] = heights(node->right);
        return { 1 + min, 1 + max };
    } else {
        return { 0, 0 };
    }
}

bool check(Node * node) {
    auto [min, max] = heights(node);
    return min == max;
}
```